# Python: Using Pandas to Reformat List of Lists

Tags: python, json, api, pandas, enumerate

Given a list of lists that I am extracting from an API. I managed to reformat this data using pandas. However I am trying to get the averages of this data then have it print out line by line instead of in a side by side format.

```
{
    "resource": "playergamelog",
    "parameters": {
        "PlayerID": 201939,
        "LeagueID": "00",
        "Season": "2014-15",
        "SeasonType": "Regular Season"
    },
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "name": "PlayerGameLog",
            "headers": [
                "SEASON_ID",
                "Player_ID",
                "Game_ID",
                "GAME_DATE",
                "MATCHUP",
                "WL",
                "MIN",
                "FGM",
                "FGA",
                "FG_PCT",
                "FG3M",
                "FG3A",
                "FG3_PCT",
                "FTM",
                "FTA",
                "FT_PCT",
                "OREB",
                "DREB",
                "REB",
                "AST",
                "STL",
                "BLK",
                "TOV",
                "PF",
                "PTS",
                "PLUS_MINUS",
                "VIDEO_AVAILABLE"
            ],
            "rowSet": [
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401229",
                    "APR 15, 2015",
                    "GSW vs. DEN",
                    "W",
                    19,
                    4,
                    10,
                    0.4,
                    2,
                    4,
                    0.5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    2,
                    4,
                    7,
                    5,
                    0,
                    2,
                    1,
                    10,
                    14,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401212",
                    "APR 13, 2015",
                    "GSW vs. MEM",
                    "W",
                    29,
                    6,
                    10,
                    0.6,
                    3,
                    6,
                    0.5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    4,
                    8,
                    1,
                    0,
                    3,
                    2,
                    15,
                    24,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401192",
                    "APR 11, 2015",
                    "GSW vs. MIN",
                    "W",
                    35,
                    11,
                    21,
                    0.524,
                    5,
                    11,
                    0.455,
                    7,
                    8,
                    0.875,
                    0,
                    4,
                    4,
                    7,
                    4,
                    0,
                    3,
                    1,
                    34,
                    17,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401174",
                    "APR 09, 2015",
                    "GSW vs. POR",
                    "W",
                    35,
                    17,
                    23,
                    0.739,
                    8,
                    13,
                    0.615,
                    3,
                    3,
                    1,
                    1,
                    1,
                    2,
                    10,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    2,
                    45,
                    21,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401156",
                    "APR 07, 2015",
                    "GSW @ NOP",
                    "L",
                    35,
                    9,
                    18,
                    0.5,
                    5,
                    8,
                    0.625,
                    2,
                    2,
                    1,
                    1,
                    5,
                    6,
                    9,
                    1,
                    0,
                    2,
                    3,
                    25,
                    4,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401150",
                    "APR 05, 2015",
                    "GSW @ SAS",
                    "L",
                    30,
                    9,
                    17,
                    0.529,
                    5,
                    10,
                    0.5,
                    1,
                    2,
                    0.5,
                    0,
                    4,
                    4,
                    6,
                    1,
                    0,
                    4,
                    2,
                    24,
                    -16,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401142",
                    "APR 04, 2015",
                    "GSW @ DAL",
                    "W",
                    27,
                    4,
                    12,
                    0.333,
                    1,
                    4,
                    0.25,
                    2,
                    3,
                    0.667,
                    2,
                    2,
                    4,
                    3,
                    1,
                    0,
                    1,
                    1,
                    11,
                    9,
                    1
                ],
                [
                    "22014",
                    201939,
                    "0021401126",
                    "APR 02, 2015",
                    "GSW vs. PHX",
                    "W",
                    34,
                    10,
                    22,
                    0.455,
                    6,
                    11,
                    0.545,
                    2,
                    2,
                    1,
                    1,
                    7,
                    8,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    6,
                    3,
                    28,
                    -1,
                    1
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My code prints out like the following:

```
FG3A                       3.83
FG3_PCT                    0.34
FTM                        5.50
FTA                        7.17
FT_PCT                     0.78
OREB                       0.75
```

When I recieve the above response from the API. I assign

```
data= response_shots.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet'] #stats is a list
# Then I assign/store the headers obtained from this API:
headers_traditional = data['resultSets'][0]['headers'] 
# Then I take list of lists from data and reformat it using the following:
traditional_stats = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers_traditional)
# If I want to print the traditional stats with mean I use:
print(traditional_stats.mean())
```

But whenever this is done or I have more than one player I am evaluating, it prints the next players results below. I'd rather have them print side by side or all of one players averages on one line then move to the next player (while still using the same headers)

Comment: check out http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html for reshaping pandas df

Comment: At which point would I need to modify this list of lists that I have. The code first prints out the first player of interest in the pandas format. Then prints out the next one just below it.

Comment: can you please include a header of the df / the API you're using.. I'm trying to recreate

Comment: http://stats.nba.com/stats/playergamelog?LeagueID=00&PlayerID=201939&Season=2014-15&SeasonType=Regular+Season

Comment: Please edit your question to include your formatted DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, I just read your comment. It should be easy to do what you want:

**Case when all players are in the same DataFrame**

```
averages = df.groupby('Player_ID').mean().unstack()
```

**Case when each player is in a separate DataFrame**

Here I am assuming that you are getting each player one after another, looping over each Player_ID.

```
averages = pd.DataFrame()
for player in all_player_ids:
    # p_data = get data for Player_ID == player from API
    # df = whatever you do to clean p_data
    averages = averages.append(df.groupby('Player_ID').mean().unstack())
```

I am guessing you are only using the data from `p_data['resultSets']`. Try it and let me know.

Comment: If I print averages right after averages = pd.DataFrame(), I get an empty list. If I change it to averages = pd.DataFrame(data), then print averages, I get the results of each game but no averages. Then if I print averages after  averages = averages.concat(df.groupby('Player_ID').mean().unstack()), I get: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: The purpose of `averages = pd.DataFrame()` _is_ to initialize an **empty** DataFrame to which the averages will be appended. So when you `print(averages)` you are supposed to get nothing. That is the design. Please **don't change** it to `averages = pd.DataFrame(data)`. About the `AttributeError` I actually wanted to write `append`, I don't know why I wrote `concat`. I have fixed that in the answer.

Comment: and df would be the list of lists that I would be re-formatting?

Comment: Yes. But tell me something, are you creating a separate `DataFrame` for each player, or are all players in the same `DataFrame`? If they are all in the same `DataFrame`, the answer can be much simpler. I'll expand it for both cases.

Comment: I would rather have all the players in the same DataFrame as it might be easier to compare them later

Comment: That's not my question. I am asking you to tell me what you are doing with the data you are getting from the API. Edit your question to include your method of cleaning the incoming data and creating your DataFrame.